# Adding AJAX url path to current webpage url

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a webpage that has AJAX pagination and I would like to add ajax URL to the webpage url so that it is remembered on a refresh etc.

I want to get it from this : 
`localhost:8000/search`

to
`localhost:8000/search?*Then the ajax path here*`

How would i go about this? is it possible? here is my current code

```
$('.container').on('click', '.pagination a', function(zmm) {
  zmm.preventDefault();
  var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
  var sortby = $('#SortBy').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/searchsort?page=' + page,
    data: {
      SortbyList: sortby,
      name: name,
      city: city,
      country: country,
      category: category,
      sl: sl
    },
    success: function(data) {

      $('.search-results-holder').html(data).load();
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".profile").offset().top - 100
      });

    }

  })

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pushstate:

```
var newState = history.pushState(state, titel, URL);
```

See:
https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/History/pushState

and to store the url use localStorage():

```
localStorage.setItem('name', 'value'); // set
my url = localStorage.getItem('name'); // get
```

See:
https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/Web_Storage